# How do you use withStyles (isomorphic style loader) when your className has a dash in it?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-style-loader, isomorphic-style-loader

Let's say this is your SCSS:

```
.someclass {
  background: red;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDropZone from 'react-dropzone'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles'
import s from './ImageTool.scss'

class ImageTool extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div className={s.someclass}></div>

    )

  }

}

export default withStyles(ImageTool, s)
```

So this works well.

Now what happens if you need to name your class `some-class`? Clearly `className={s.some-class}` doesn't work, and neither does `className={s.someClass}` (nothing happens).

Comment: I imagine it's an object, so `s['some-class']` should work. I know it's not css-like, but camel case is usually preferred when using styles like this.

Comment: Why wouldn't `className={s['some-class']}` work?

Comment: Trying out @mpen suggestion

Comment: @AlexGuerra actually please make an answer

Comment: It didn't click for me that this is just javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code between the curly braces in JSX is just JavaScript and `s` is just an object. i.e., you can access properties of `s` just like you normally would in JS, even if they contain dashes, spaces or other funny characters.

Specifically, you can write:

```
<div className={s['some-class']}></div>
```